# Is there a way to generate a push ID from the Console in the new Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have a `listing` node in my Database and wanted to add data into it from the web console. I want to have a push ID as the key of the object. Something like this :

```
{
    "listing": {
        "4acd4g1OreMyo2FkW6DlQH7ZhvY2": {
            "name": "abc",
            "location": "xyz"
        }
    }
}
```

where '4acd4g1OreMyo2FkW6DlQH7ZhvY2' would be the auto generated push ID.

I know it can be done using the Android/iOS/JS SDKs (using the `push` method). But is this possible from the console?

Comment: What do you mean "from the web console"?

Comment: Where you say `UID` do you mean the value generated by calling `push()` (or `childByAutoId` if you're on iOS)?

Comment: Yes. The same thing. Isn't that what its called? I heard it in the I/O talks.

Comment: By 'web console' i mean the Firebase website - console.firebase.google.com

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen, since you're with Firebase, I just wanted to second Rohith's demand for being able to create new push keys from within the web console. There are plenty of use cases for unit testing but also in production where it'd come in extremely handy to hit a button that generates a new push key (sounds simple to implement). The Firebase console GUI has improved so much over the last year and I think it's an awesome tool really. This would definitely be another great addition!

Comment: I hear you Ben! While chances are small that this will be added to the RTDB console at this point, you can cast your vote by [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). Note that the Firestore console *does* have a button to generate a GUID for a new document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the console doesn't support it currently. I've been using firebase for a while and I've never needed it :)

Comment: I've had a lot of cases with young projects and prototypes where it would have been nice to manually enter a data item and have it get keyed,  rather than having to write server or client code to do it (especially when I don't want people to be able to create that data, I just want to add some quickly for test purposes).

Comment: me too, that's weird

Answer (score 0):

while firebase console doesn't support it officially, there is a service called [mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com/) that can generate firebase random id. Make sure to pick firebase option in the format dropdown

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).